# How to connect my Python3 code to my local machine's clock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clock

Assuming I've written a Python code, which displays the time as long as you keep the program running on the console. Maybe I'll run my code at 4 AM the first time, and next time at 6 PM and so on. So How could I tell my code to start the clock from 5 AM if I'm running it at 5 AM, for example? To me it seems like my code needs to be connected to some external clock. Can someone help me with this? I really didn't know how to search this question on Google. Any hints, tips or solutions will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are you trying to achive exactly? One clock that wait until the specified time is reached?

Comment: Is it possible to have the python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "datetime" module.

The syntax would be the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a simple custom timer:

```
import time

def Timer_Tick(delay): #delay = time to wait in seconds
    while True:
        time_remaining = delay-time.time()%delay # calculate the remaining before execute
        time.sleep(time_remaining) # wait the remaining time
        # Your code

Timer_Tick(300) # This timer execute each 5 minutes (eg. 14:00, 14:05, 14:10, ..)
```

You can run this code in a separate thread, so it count for you the time and when executed you run your actions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want your code to calculate how long it has been since you started its execution. When your program starts call:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()
```

Then every time you want to check how long it has been since your code started, call:

```
datetime.now()-start_time
```

Which outputs

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=5, microseconds=358359)
```

Comment: No, I want my program to display what time it is by the time I run it, and keep track of time until I end the program. But I'm not sure how my program should actually know what time it is every time I run it.

Comment: Then simply calling datetime.now() will show you what time it is at execution